# it should be possible to use interfaces with truffle

Tags: truffle

we have an interface contract which we would like to declare as `interface`I have created a file with only this code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.14;


interface UserDirectoryFactoryI {
    function createUserDirectory(address root, address user, address rolesContract) returns (address);
}
```

when compiling with `solc` it works. when using `truffle compile` it end in error

```
SyntaxError: Expected "contract", "import", "library", "pragma", "using", comment, end of input, end of line, or whitespace but "i" found.
    at peg$buildStructuredError (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:177767:12)
    at Object.peg$parse [as parse] (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:181366:11)
    at Object.parse (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:89808:23)
    at /Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:57847:36
    at /Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:50141:5
    at /Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:66021:16
    at next (/Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:75933:18)
    at /Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:50126:7
    at /Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:96942:5
    at /Users/mroon/.nvm/versions/node/v8.5.0/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:75838:16
```

If `interface`is replaced with `contract`it works as intended

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check issue #67 and PR #68 on Github.

- https://github.com/ConsenSys/solidity-parser/issues/67
- https://github.com/ConsenSys/solidity-parser/pull/68

Apparently it has been fixed but not yet released. You could ping them over there.